# Plugin.Connectivity not being recognized

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working with someone on an app and I cloned their branch from our git repository. They added a NuGet Package called Xam.Plugin.Connectivity.

However, it's not recognizing this in our utils page. It just says that the type or namespace "Plugin" could not be found. I made sure to get the most up to date version and I made sure that I added it to the entire solution. It works for him, but we can't seem to figure out why it is not working for me.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: To be specific, i just mean the error that comes up is type or namespace "Plugin" cannot be found.

Comment: Add "using Plugin.Connectivity;" in you class above namespace. If you installed nuget correctly there is no reason for it to no work.

Comment: Yesterday I got this too for old project. Tried restoring packages. Right clicked on this package, tried updating it. Clean, Rebuild and it worked for me. Hope this may help.

Comment: If restoring still doesn't work. Delete the package from your projects packages folder. When you rebuild, a clean package will be downloaded.